# Url parameters in Flask (modifiers '+', '-' to sort)

Tags: python-3.x, url, flask, flask-restful

I'm ussing Flask with Python3. I need to sort my objects ussing the modifier '+' or '-' in the `order` argumnent of my url.

```
/objects?order=name+
```

I use the `request.args`(ImmutableDict) object to get `GET` arguments but I lose the last character of the string "the modifier char" and is replaced with a blank character.

request.args[order] = 'name '

The query string from request is ok, I think Flask is losing the '+' when translate the query string to args.

```
request.query_string = 'order=name+'
```

Anyway I can use an extra argument to solve it, but the modifier is cool to use.

```
/objects?order=name&mod=asc
```

Any ideas?,
Thanks

Comment: You maybe should encode `+` using `%2B` since `+` is often used for encoding spaces.

Comment: @BenoîtLatinier its works! Thanks!